# How do I compare two CSV files in PIG, and output only the different columns?

Tags: csv, apache-pig

Between an older csv file and a newer one, I want to find what fields have changed on rows with the same key. For example, if the unique key is in field $2, and we have two files:

> ```
> Old csv file: 
>      FIELD1,FIELD2,ID,FIELD4 
>      a,a,key1,a 
>      b,b,key2,b
>
> New csv file:  
>      FIELD1,FIELD2,ID,FIELD4
>      a,a2,key1,a2 
>      b,b,key2,b
> ```

Desired output something like:

> ```
>      {FIELD2:a2,ID:key1,FIELD4:a2}
> ```

or in other words, on the row with ID = key1, the 2nd and 4th fields changed, and these are the changed values.

A pig script that outputs the whole row if any field has changed, is:

```
old = load '$old' using PigStorage('\n') as (line:chararray);
new = load '$new' using PigStorage('\n') as (line:chararray);
cg = cogroup old by line, new by line;
new_only = foreach (filter cg by IsEmpty(old)) generate flatten(new);
store new_only into '$changes';
```

My initial idea (I'm not sure how to complete it) is:

```
old = LOAD $old USING PigStorage('|');
new = LOAD $new USING PigStorage('|');
cogroup_data = COGROUP old by $2, new by $2 -- 3rd column is unique key
diff_data = FOREACH cogroup_data GENERATE DIFF(old,new);
-- ({(a,a,key2,a),(a,a2,key2,a2)})
-- ? what goes here ?
```

Comment: Examples with data would be very helpful here.

Comment: It seems like you have already tried to describe what you want, but without an actual example of two (small) input files it is still hard to see what exactly you want. -- Based on just the description I wonder whether this is something that someone would want to use Pig for.